# RabbitMQ drop message instead of placing it on DLX queue?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I have installed a local RabbitMQ service where a couple of queues has been added with the help of 3 .NET C# microservices. There is no problems to send and receive message but when they reach the expire time (5 sec for test) the message is dropped and lost!?

RabbitMQ Manager > MyAppResponse queue has these settings:

```
x-dead-letter-exchange: direct_exchange.dlx
x-dead-letter-routing-key:  MyAppResponse.dlx
x-message-ttl:  5000
durable:    true
```

RabbitMQ Manager > MyAppResponse.dlx queue has these settings:

```
x-dead-letter-exchange: direct_exchange.dlx
x-dead-letter-routing-key:  MyAppResponse
x-message-ttl:  5000
durable:    true
```

This should mean that incoming messages will remain on the MyAppResponse queue for 5 sec and then moved over to MyAppResponse.dlx. The message will remain here for another 5 sec and then put back on the original queue: MyAppResponse, this is how I want it to work.

I can see that the message arrives at the MyAppResponse and after 5 sec the message disappears, but it is not appearing on the MyAppResponse.dlx queue.

After a lot of searching, I found the log file here: c:\users\myname\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log\rabbit@WR90THCZV.log, it does however say nothing about dropping any messages. I’m still not sure how the rabbitMQ config works, the manual says it should be placed in a specific location but there is only an advanced.config. I suppose I must create it myself and find out what goes in it.

Anyway, I know that messages will be dropped if the DLX queue do not exist but in this case it does (double checked). I do also not have any service that are listening on any DLX queues. So why is the messages dropped and not put on the DLX?

**EDIT1 :** With the help of @Chad Knutson(comments) it seems like the binding between exchanges are not correct.

I have added the following bindings :

MyAppResponse >
FROM: direct_exchange, Routing key: MyAppResponse, Arg:None

MyAppResponse.dlx >
FROM: direct_exchange.dlx, Routing key: SendSharedTreatment.dlx, Arg:None

I can now see that after 5 sec the message are moved from MyAppResponse to MyAppResponse.dlx. But after 5 sec in the DLX the message is dropped and not put back on the MyAppResponse?

**EDIT2 :** So messages are sent to exchanges and I got 2; `direct_exchange` and `direct_exchange.dlx`. A binding needs to connect the `direct_exchange` with the `MyAppResponse` to be able to send any message to this queue.

The MyAppResponse points out a DLX exchange and queue; `direct_exhange.dlx`, `MyAppResponse.dlx`. This means that there have to be an other bidning connecting `direct_exhange.dlx` with the `MyAppResponse.dlx` queue.

At this point we have the following setup :

```
direct_exchange > MyAppResponse
direct_exchange.dlx > MyAppResponse.dlx
```

Sending a message to the `direct_exchange` with routing-key `MyAppResponse` works fine. When the time is up the message are sent from `MyAppResponse` to `direct_exchange.dlx` with routing key `MyAppResponse.dlx` and this do also work fine.

But when the time is up on the dlx queue it is not sent back to the `direct_exchange` > `MyAppResponse` even while this is the registered dead-letter exchange and queue?

Regards

Comment: Can you see the RabbitMQ console management in the browser?

Comment: It sounds like the queue MyAppResponse.dlx does not have a binding to exchange direct_exchange.dlx with routing key MyAppResponse.dlx.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, RabbitMQ Managment are the webpage that show statistics, connections, channels, exchanges, queues and users. Its possible to create and/or alter some of the settings but usally I just delete the queues and exchanges and then let the microservices create them again with new settings. I haven't found any console or log in this local webpage.

Comment: @ChadKnutson, the DLX exchange and routing-key is set under Queues > MyAppResponse.dlx > Details > Features, it what I pasted in to my post above. There is 1  Binding = Default exchamge binding > This queue, not sure if that is correct? If I look at the orignal queue MyAppResponse there is 2 bindings, one Default exchange binding but also a direct_exchange. It looks like the DLX queue is missing the direct_exchange.dlx as you suggest. Will look into adding it.

Comment: @ChadKnutson, added a binding (direct_exchange.dlx, MyAppResponse.dlx, ) and that help a bit, the message appeared in the DLX. But it once again was droped when the time was up? In this case I need it to transfer to SendSharedTreatment again.

Comment: Progress!  The properties for the DLX queue show that messages should be dropped after 5 seconds.  If you want to keep them, you need to add the bindings listed for dead lettering to your target queue.  Same procedure as for the first dead lettering process.

Comment: @ChadKnutson, thanks! its a bit strange becouse I am sure this was working before but I never hade any binding code. I will look into how to create it the way I need. If you like you could add a solution to this question.

Comment: @ChadKnutson, have now tried to add bindings, check the edit in my post. It still won't jump back on the main queue.

Comment: It sounds like you still don't have a binding from exchange 'direct_exchange.dlx' to the queue 'MyAppResponse'.  Possible options are (a) to add that binding or (b) to change the dead letter exchange for the queue 'MyAppResponse.dl' to empty string [the default exchange] with routing key set to 'MyAppResponse'.

Comment: How should that exchange binding look like? Have tried the following on direct_exchange.dlx : ToQueue > MyAppResponse, RoutingLey > MyAppResponse and ToExchange > direct_exchange, RoutingKey > MyAppResponse but none of them works, the message is still droped when it is timed out on the DLX?

Comment: The direct_exchange have only 1 bidning and its : To > MyAppResponse RoutingKey > MyAppResponse and it works just fine sending expired messages to the direct_exchange.dlx queue. The direct_exchange.dlx have the same binding but with DLX : To > MyAppResponse.dlx RoutingKey > MyAppResponse.dlx.