# How to use internal logging in RabbitMQ?

Tags: logging, rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ on Windows 10 and created a .NET C# producer and consumer. After some problems that can be read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859116/rabbitmq-drop-message-instead-of-placing-it-on-dlx-queue) I started to look for internal logs.

The documentation seems to not be updated for Windows but after a while I found a internal log here `C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log\rabbit@[computername].log`. This log does however not log anything about messages.

So, after some more digging I found out that I should create `C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf` with the following content:

log.exchange = true
log.exchange.level = debug

After restart, amq.rabbitmq.log and amq.rabbitmq.log exchanges are created. I first created a binding to my log queue with no routing key but that did not work. I recreated the binding with routing key # and now I get a lot of messages into the log queue. All the messages are however unacked so I can´t look at them!? Also, there is so many that it would be great if I could look at them like a regular log and not by fetching individual entries.

After even more digging I found a feature called [Firehose Tracer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html), did not really get it working at first but after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftIKXFLdYZQ&ab_channel=MikeM%C3%B8llerNielsen) I get published and delivered messages into a created log queue. What I learned here is that there is there is built-in routing keys that I probably need to use : publish.#, deliver.#, there is probably routing keys for dropped messages as well?

What I need is a log that show the message flow and why messages are dropped. I’m a bit surprised that it’s this complicated just to get proper log data from RabbitMQ.

**EDIT 1:** After a while the messages in my log queue was set to Ready instead of Unacked and I could take a look at them. After placing a message on my main queue an letting it jump to DLX and then get lost there was about 60 log rows in the log queue. None of them explained what happened to the message, mainly it was about connection status and granting user.

I also tried removing the bindings from the amq.rabbitmq.trace and recreated  one of them with just # as routing key. After letting a message through the flow until it was lost I only got 1 message in trace queue.

So still no luck.

Comment: It sounds like you have a complex setup. Stack Overflow is not a good forum for diagnosing issues like these. Please post a message to the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users) and we can continue the discussion there. Provide your RMQ configuration and export your full RabbitMQ definitions and provide code that I can run to publish a message the same way you are. Ideally, you provide a github repo I can clone and work from. Thanks (PS I'm a member of the core RMQ team).

Comment: Thanks, I have now created a sample project and posted in the group.